# SQL: join vs where

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, join, where-clause

To simplify things, mine is a situation with two tables with a one-to-many (or possibly one-to-none in some cases) relationship: e.g. accounts and payments made, clients and orders placed, etc. Every payment/order can only be associated to 1 account, but an account may have zero, 1 or multiple payments associated to it.
If I want to calculate the total number of payments/orders per each account/client, I’d write something like this:

```
Select c.clientid
,coalesce(o.NumOrders,0) as NumOrders

From clients c

Left outer join
( select clientid, count(*) as NumOrders from orders group by clientid ) o
on c.clientid = o.clientid
```

However, I have also seen this type of coding:

```
Select c.clientid
, ( select count(orders.clientid) from orders where orders.clientid = c.clientid) as NumOrders

From clients c
```

Do you have any comments on which approach would be preferable and why?

I find the latter harder to read, but maybe it’s just my habit. As for performance, it seems the first is faster if I have no where clause, but if I have a where clause (e.g. a condition which only returns 1,000 records from a 2.2 million-record clients table) then the latter seems faster.

I use PostgreSQL 9.1 and Microsoft SQL Server 2014.Thank you!

Comment: just cross check query execution plan

Comment: you answer yourselve, use `join` to join the tables and `where` clause to restrict the domain to get less records.

Comment: so you don't need to join for this example.  You can just do select o.clientid, count(*) from orders o group by o.clientid

Comment: I honestly fail to understand what would be too broad about my question. Could you help me understand? I provided minimalist examples of two ways of getting to the same output, and asked pros and cons of each. It's a very detailed question, not one of those how-long-is-a-piece-of-string type of question. I guess I am not familiar enough with stack overflow, but the help centre doesn't help clarify this point.

Comment: Is there a way to contact the moderators? If there is, I couldn't find it. I have already received good answers, so the argument that 'There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format' is utter nonsense...

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer

```
Select c.clientid
,count(o.clientid) as NumOrders

From clients c

Left outer join orders o on c.clientid = o.clientid

group by c.clientid
```

as it is simple and clear.

If I would ahve to choose between your both versions, I would prefer the second, as it is shorter (less code to have to read and try to understand), but not somehow tricky. The first one has to deal with NULL handling which makes things more complex then necessary.

Comment: I agree that it is far better to avoid the subquery, but I don't think this quite works.  You want to join on the `clientid` columns, for one thing, but more importantly, you want something like `count(o.orderid)`, else you will get a count of 1 for clients with no orders.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good point! I edited my answer.

Comment: The updated version will still return a count of 1 for clients without any orders.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Right! Maybe I should have checked my statement more closely.

Answer (score 1):

This version:

```
Select c.clientid,
       ( select count(o.clientid) from orders o where o.clientid = c.clientid
       ) as NumOrders
From clients c;
```

Has a major advantage.  The following pretty much explains it:

```
select c.*, . . .
```

That is, you can select whatever columns you like and you don't have to put them into a `group by` clause.  As a reminder, you cannot put `*` into the `group by`.

In your case, SQL Server and Postgres have pretty good optimizers, so either should be able to take advantage of indexes.  Not all SQL engines are so smart.  MySQL, in particular, is better at using an index on `orders` in the first case than in the `group by` case.

That said, the second version is fine, standard SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

Left join to the derived table instead of the correlated subquery in the select clause is generally going to be more efficient. A correlated subquery forces a looped subquery whereas a left join can use a looped or hash join. You do want to include the group by within the derived table like you have in your example because it can use an index on the foreign key to calculate the aggregate whereas grouping against just a simple left join will not. If you have a where clause, it depends on which table it's filtering on. If you're filtering on the orders table, then make sure you have the where clause inside the derived table. If you're SIGNIFICANTLY filtering down the number of rows in the clients table with a where clause, then yes, a correlated subquery like your second example will perform faster doing just a few looped subqueries instead of trying to calculate the aggregated totals across the entire table, which may be millions of orders. I would however suggest in that instance that you use outer apply to perform the correlated subquery in the join clause instead of in the select clause because it will give you access to other columns in the table if need be, and has no real downside. So I would generally recommend your first example:

```
Select c.clientid
,coalesce(o.NumOrders,0) as NumOrders

From clients c

Left outer join
( select clientid, count(*) as NumOrders from orders group by clientid ) o
on c.clientid = o.clientid
```